# Multiple resize image upload with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image-upload, intervention

I'm working to make a multi upload image to database with intervention resizer in Laravel.

This is what I'm coding right now in my controller
`imgProdukProc` controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use File;
use Image;
use App\imgProd;

.....

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('img')){
            foreach ($request->file('img') as $image) {
            if ($image->isValid()) {

                $img = new imgProd();
                $image_name = uniqid() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = public_path('/img/prod');
                $imgx = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
                $imgx->resize(360, 360, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save($path.'/'.$image_name);

                $img->id_prod = $request->get('id_prod');
                $img->pics = 'img/prod/'.$image_name;

                $date=date_create('now');
                $format = date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
                $img->date = $format;
                $img->save();
                return redirect('adminImgProd')->with('success', 'Picture successfully added ');
            }
        }          
    }
}
```

and this is my views

**adminImgProd Views**

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{url('adminImgProd')}}" method='post'>
@csrf

<div class="form-group">
<label>CODE PRODUCT</label>
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id='id_prod' name='id_prod' required="required" />
<span class="input-group-addon"><button type="button" onClick="javascript:openWindow2();">Select</button></span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>IMAGE PRODUCT</label>
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span>
<input multiple type="file" class="form-control" name='img[]' id='file-input' required="required" /></div>
</div>
```

Code above is working , but somehow when I tried to upload 2 images or 3 images the only image saved both in target folder and in database is only one and it is the last one

Where is my code mistake , or just my code simply wrong from the start ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your `return` in your `foreach`, so after 1 loop, it will return and exit your function :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('img')){
        foreach ($request->file('img') as $image) {
            if ($image->isValid()) {

                $img = new imgProd();
                $image_name = uniqid() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = public_path('/img/prod');
                $imgx = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
                $imgx->resize(360, 360, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save($path.'/'.$image_name);

                $img->id_prod = $request->get('id_prod');
                $img->pics = 'img/prod/'.$image_name;

                $date=date_create('now');
                $format = date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
                $img->date = $format;
                $img->save();
            }
        }

        return redirect('adminImgProd')->with('success', 'Picture successfully added ');
    }
}
```

Comment: oh my what a beginner mistake, thank you for pointing it out ! +1 , btw is there any way to make my controller run more efficient and look clean ? , just asking .

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following for multiple images:

```
   $images = $request->file('images');

   foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
     if ($request->hasFile('images') && $request->file('images')[$key]->isValid()) {
        $path = $request->images[$key]->store('public/images');
        $path = basename($path);

        $image = new ProductImages();
        $image->product_id = $request->get('product_id');
        $image->photo = $path;
        $image->save();
      }
   }
```

I hope it would helpful.